Django project not fetching static files
I am developing a small app for my course in Django. Now, I am trying to bring my project to a cloud system, in this case using Heroku, however it seems that I have an issue with fetching my static files when running the collectstatic command. I get the following error:
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mlopez/journal_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mlopez/journal_project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 368, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 278, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/files/storage/filesystem.py", line 165, in exists
    return os.path.lexists(self.path(name))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mlopez/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 39, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Here are my settings.py:
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@9*9cg2wtc+*%y920pa1-jfxunvkc8&gb#kwafbg2_rq!i&(nx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1').split(',')

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'entries',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'journal_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'journal_backend.wsgi.application'

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'entries.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

print("STATIC_ROOT is set to:", STATIC_ROOT)


My directory is as follows: files: root/staticfiles and app: root/app.
Any orientation is highly appreciated, thank you!
I added the STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') line in settings.py to indicate where to collect those files.
I currently don't have any static files, but as far as the documentation I should at least get the following:
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to '/path/to/staticfiles', 0 unmodified.


Have you tried running python manage.py check to see if anything is not configured correctly?
It could be that on the commandline you are not picking up the correct django settings file.

@MattSeymour thank you for your answer. I don't have any system issues at the moment.

The error message references a local path: /Users/mlopez. Are you trying to do this on Heroku or locally?

@Chris I'm running it locally for now, as the error hasn't resolved in this environment. my project is in the path /Users/mlopez/journal_project/staticfiles

Problem solved! When I copied my project I had another settings.py file which I was configuring, and kept throwing the error message. I found the real file to which the project refers to and added STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') which works now. Thank you!
